# Docker SDK for python in docker swarm with multiple nodes

Tags: python, docker, docker-swarm

How can I use the docker package in Python (Docker SDK for python) with multiple nodes?
I am running my python script from a manager node and I am trying to get the container logs on one of the other node. I thought the docker socket could access all the other nodes docker daemons but it seems I can only list the containers of the current node.

```
client = docker.APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
client.logs(container=container_id, stream=True, timestamps=True, follow=True)
```

This code raise the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.40/containers/<container_id>/json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most objects that are not part of the swarm api - containers, volumes etc. are not cluster aware and must be queried on the specific node.

Objects that swarm mode adds: services, tasks, configs, secrets etc. - these can be queried from the manager.